# Report viewer Does not display Dataset

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to develop one **Winform App** with **C#** and **SQL** As Data backed.

I'm stuck at a particular Place.

I have a Winform report viewer that is supposed to display data which is going to be retrieved using two `datetimepicker control`. Here is my code for that:

```
`SqlConnection dat = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=2011-GOA-RCC3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IOB_Comm;Integrated Security=True");
            dat.Open();
            SqlCommand dat1 = new SqlCommand();
            dat1.Connection = dat;
            dat1.CommandText = "Select * from DCR Where Comp_Date Between '"+ dateTimePicker1.Text +"' And '"+ dateTimePicker2.Text +"' Order By Comp_Date Asc" ;
            dat1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter nb = new SqlDataAdapter(dat1);
            DataSet mn = new DataSet();
            nb.Fill(mn);`
```

Now the code works fine till there, then to i go for databind,sort of to say at the least, between the dataset and the report viewer. here is the code for that,..

```
DataTable dsts = new DataTable();
            dsts.TableName = "dt";
            dsts = mn.Tables[0];
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rdc = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("dt", dsts);

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdc);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = mn.Tables[0];//to check if dataset has data.
```

Here in lies my problem. The code complies fine, but the output is not as i expect. 
I'm able to view the data in **Datagridview**, but not the report viewer...

Can you guys help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem my self...

I just added a group table in the rdlc report and recreating all the datatable using the default dataset(created at using the desing wizard) to point the column/row data...

It's working very smoothly now, i'm able to view all the queried data in the report viewver...